# Using lifetimes, Cow<str>, and Builder pattern in harmony

Tags: rust

I'm still getting my head around lifetimes in Rust and I have the following struct I'd like to create:

```rust
use std::{
    borrow::Cow,
    marker::PhantomData,
};
struct Init;
struct Parsed;
struct Html;

/// A Markdown parser built using **Pest**.
pub struct Parkdown<'a, TState = Init> {
    /// raw markdown content
    pub content: Cow<'a, str>,
    /// the file which the content was derived from
    /// (if provided)
    file: Option<String>,
    /// rule used to parse
    pub rule: Rule,
    /// "pairs" produced by the rule
    pairs: Option<Pairs<'a, Rule>>,

    state: PhantomData<TState>,
}
```

There's nothing wrong with the struct itself but I'm using the `Init`,`Parsed`, and `Html` structs to dictate the API state that `Parkdown` should expose and I'm wanting to use a *builder pattern* so that I can move from one state to another. The primary goal which I'm seemingly unable to overcome is preserving a borrowed `&str` passed into content without making a copy when changing `TState`.

Said more succinctly, i want to implement a `parse` method on `Parkdown<'_, Init>` which will return a `Parsed` version of Parkdown:

```rust
impl<'a, Init> Parkdown<'a, Init> {
    pub fn new(content: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self {
            content: Cow::Borrowed(content),
            rule: Rule::file,
            file: None,
            pairs: None,
            state: PhantomData::<Init>,
        }
    }

    pub fn parse<'b>(&'b self) -> Result<Parkdown<'b, Parsed>, Err> {
        let pairs: Pairs<'b, Rule> = Markdown::parse(
            self.rule, //
            &self.content,
        )?;

        let p: Parkdown<'b, Parsed> = Parkdown {
            state: PhantomData::<Parsed>,
            pairs: Some(pairs),
            // Error is here 
            content: self.content,
            rule: self.rule,
            file: self.file.clone(),
        };
        Ok(p)
    }
```

I've tried this and half-a-dozen variants but can't get it to compile. In this incarnation the complaint is that I can't pass along the `Cow<str>` because it doesn't implement the **Copy** trait but in fact my goal is to *not* copy it along but maintain the reference in cases where we have a borrowed reference passed in.

I guess to express my goal a bit more clearly I might also mention that there *are* cases where an owned variant of the Cow will also exist as can be seen with these two other implementation functions:

```
impl<'a, Init> Parkdown<'a, Init> {
    // ...

    pub fn new_owned(content: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            content: Cow::Owned(content),
            rule: Rule::file,
            file: None,
            pairs: None,
            state: PhantomData::<Init>,
        }
    }

    pub fn from_file(file: &str) -> Result<Parkdown<'a, Init>, Err> {
        let content = read_to_string(&file)?;

        let mut p = Parkdown::new_owned(content);
        p.file = Some(file.to_string());

        Ok(p)
    }
```

A working version of this code can be found as the `p_pest` package in this repo: [Parsing Repo](https://github.com/yankeeinlondon/parsing/tree/1be40fb530fa725c9ed879048b786c0ec667833a).

---

It was suggested by @ChayimFriedman to use `self` versus `&self`. My interpretation is the intent was to do the following for the `parse()` function:

```rust
pub fn parse(self) -> Result<Parkdown<'a, Parsed>> {
    color_eyre::install()?;
    let pairs: Pairs<'a, Rule> = Markdown::parse(
        self.rule, //
        &self.content,
    )?;

    self.pairs = Some(pairs);
    // Error is here 
    self.state = PhantomData::<Parsed>;

    Ok(self)
}
```

> expected struct `PhantomData<Init>` found struct
> `PhantomData<Parsed>`

but this doesn't work because `state` is a generic on Parkdown so it can't be changed.

Here's the explicit error:
[image: err msg]

Comment: What will happen when the code contains a `Cow::Owned` and `parse()` is called? Why not take `self`, not by reference?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman parse() is intended to simply move the struct to the `Parsed` state (assuming no errors occur). If you change to `self` from `&self` then `content` property now errors because it is a borrow value. Although potentially I'm not fully understanding what you're suggesting. Could you pose question as an "answer"?

Comment: `content` _currently_ errors, it should not if you move `self`.

Comment: If you change `pub fn parse<'b>(&'b self) -> Result<Parkdown<'b, Parsed>, Err> {` to `pub fn parse(self) -> Result<Parkdown<'a, Parsed>, Err> {`, what is the result?

Comment: If you just want to pass along to the `Parsed` version an immutable reference to `self.content`, passing it along with a new `Cow` should work: `content: Cow::Borrowed(&self.content)`

Comment: @EvilTak I could have sworn I tried this but I "tried it again" and it worked

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I have updated the question to indicate why your approach does not work

Comment: Instead of setting `self.state`, return a new struct entirely aka `Ok(Parkdown { pairs, ..... })`

Comment: @PitaJ that will not work for reasons already stated

Comment: This was not what I meant, I meant something [like that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07a369c992e13acc3a24be4a533534b3).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman actually I cut and pasted your solution and it doesn't work; I'll add the error message to question